# How to use "once/when" from "redux-when" library while using connect?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Usually when i want to import an action i simply import it as -

```
import { LoginApi, getUserInfo, combine } from "../actions/loginAction";
```

and then call that specific action using `this.props.LoginApi()`.

However,I am trying to use redux-when and am not really sure how to use it. Can somebody please help?